# sed + add word before string only if not exists

Tags: text-processing, sed, configuration

We have the following line in a file on Linux:

```
discovery.uri=http://master.navada.com:8800
```

we want to add the word `koko` before `master`, so I just do:

```
sed –i 's/master/kokomaster/' file
```

which gives:

```
discovery.uri=http://kokomaster.navada.com:8800
```

but what we want is to add `koko` only if `koko` isn't already present before `master`.

For example, the next time that we run

```
sed –i 's/master/kokomaster/' file
```

the line will be:

```
discovery.uri=http://kokokokomaster.navada.com:8800
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace a bit more to avoid this problem:

```
sed -i sX/masterX/kokomasterX file
```

This replaces “/master”, so the next time you run it, nothing will be replaced, since “/kokomaster” doesn’t match.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -i '/kokomaster/!s/master/koko&/' file
```

First test whether the string `kokomaster` exists on the line, and if it doesn't, do the substitution.  This is almost a literal translation of "but what we want is to add the `koko` word only if `koko` not exists before `master` word" into `sed`.

The `&` in the replacement part of the substitution will be replaced by the text matched by the pattern part (i.e. `master`).

---

After reading the comments (see below), you may want to use something more specific that would actually only modify the server name portion of the URI, and not any `master` string elsewhere, even if `kokomaster` occurred (or not) in the URI path:

```
sed -i 's,^\(discovery\.uri=http://\)\(master\),\1koko\2,' file
```

You may even want to go as far as matching the exact and *full* line that you'd want to replace, just to avoid even hypothetical mistakes:

```
sed -i 's,^\(discovery\.uri=http://\)\(master\.navada\.com:8800\)$,\1koko\2,' file
```

If the configuration file is written in JSON or some other well know format, you would *not use `sed` at all*, but `jq` or some other apropriate tool specifically written for handling files of that format.

Comment: That wouldn't work on `discovery.uri=http://master.navada.com:8800/kokomaster` though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Correct, as per the explicit specification from the user.

Comment: Not sure I follow. In `discovery.uri=http://master.navada.com:8800/kokomaster`, there's no `koko` before the first `master`. Yet, that `sed` line doesn't add one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, that was half a joke, but it _is_ actually what the user specified. If the string `koko` does not already occur before `master`, it should not be added again. That's what's requested, and that's what I did, pedantically following the request to the letter. In your string, `koko` already occurs right before `master`, so it's not added again.

Comment: @Kusalananda nope. The `master` in the server name needs to be replaced even if there may be some `kokomaster` in the path. Pedanticly. I guess the OP doesn't care.

Comment: @Philippos If you want to be picky, you could also argue that the accepted answer has a similar flaw as it would replace `master` in the path of the URI if there was no `master` in the server name.

Comment: As written, I don't think the OP would care. I'm not picky, just explaining Stephane's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
sed 's/\(koko\)*master/kokomaster/'
```

so `master` and any number of preceeding `koko`s get replaced.

Comment: Or better, `sed 's/\(koko\)\{0,1\}master/kokomaster/'` to avoid replacing `kokokokomaster` with `kokomaster`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to other tools:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!koko)master/kokomaster/' file
```

The `(?>!foo)` is a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so `(?<!koko)master` will only match `master` when not preceded by `koko`.

Answer (score 2):

I have used below awk command to do the same

command

```
awk '$0 !~/kokomaster/{gsub("master","kokomaster",$0)}1'  filename >file_tmp && mv file_tmp filename
```

output

```
discovery.uri=http://kokomaster.navada.com:8800
discovery.uri=http://kokomaster.navada.com:8800
```