# sed to add character before another between certain delimiters

Tags: sed

So I want to take the questions found in [sed + add word before string only if not exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523302/sed-add-word-before-string-only-if-not-exists) and [sed -- replace a character in a string when the preceding character is not a certain character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714758/sed-replace-a-character-in-a-string-when-the-preceding-character-is-not-a-cer) and take it a little bit further.

Say I have a file and I want to replace all `_` with `\_`, but I have two constraints:

1. If `_` is already preceded by a `\` then I don't want anything to happen. (We never get `\\` so no need to worry about that case)
2. We should *only* make this replacement if `_` appears before two delimiters. For example, between `start[` and `]end`.

As an example, the following:

```
Pretending_we have \_ some start[text that\_is really_cool]end.
Then \_nothing_ would start[happen_ to\_ that crew_]end
```

Would get converted to

```
Pretending_we have \_ some start[text that\_is really\_cool]end.
Then \_nothing_ would start[happen\_ to\_ that crew\_]end
```

**Note:** I know that in some cases we'd like to chain sed by replacing every instance of `\_` with something that is not used and then replacing all `_` with `\_` and then reversing the first change. But I'd prefer to not do that because I don't know what other characters might be present in the code, so I'd like to do it directly if possible.

Also, I'll be doing this in both vim and terminal (vim as a test run to make sure it's working and then terminal to handle this on 11 different files.) I don't know enough about the differences between the two, but figured I'd mention it in case one is easier than another.

**Edit:** To answer some questions brought up:

1. perl/sed/vim are all acceptable methods to handle the problem. Just not sure what the best approach was and I'm much more comfortable with sed/vim's regex and hence why I mentioned those. (By conflating sed and vim I think I caused confusion so sorry about that. I'm used to using sed and vim regex to handle most of my regex needs, and from what I've noticed usually what I do on one works perfectly on the other. So I'm assuming they're using the same regex handling, but that's probably not a safe assumption I should be making and will look that up. Sorry about the confusion).
2. I'm using ubuntu
3. Generally the start/end delimiters will be on the same line so theoretically that can be a safe assumption (although if you know how to do it so line doesn't matter, that would be good too for future people looking at a problem like this)

Comment: Wait, how is vim connected to sed? Are you asking for a sed command or a vim replacement command? Also, does this _have_ to be sed or can we use something that understands more powerful regular expressions like perl? And most importantly: what operating system are you using? This is particularly relevant if you need `sed` since different systems have different `sed` implementations.

Comment: And another thing, will these delimiters always be on the same line? Can you have `start[` on line 4 and `]end` on line 37?

Comment: They'll generally be on the same line. Should have included that.

The syntax for sed and vim is generally the same when using 's/.../.../g'. So I meant "the same" in that regards. It's just standard ubuntu (I'll update with these answers too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `perl` for that:

```
perl -pe 's{start\[.*?\]end}{$& =~ s{\\?_}{\\_}gr}ge' < your-file
```

Where we `s`ubstitute¹ all (`g`) the `start[...]end` sequences with the same (`$&` which contains what was matched by the regexp) where we've `s`ubstituded and `r`eturned all (`g`) the `_`s optionally (`?`) preceded by a `\` with `\_`. The `e` flag is to tell that the replacement (`$& =~ s{\\?_}{\\_}gr`) is to be `e`valuated as code.

That assumes there are no nested `start[...]end`.

If `start[...]end`s may span several lines, add the `-0777` option (set the record separator to something impossible), so the input be processed as a whole instead of one line at a time.

---

<sup>¹ using the same `s/pattern/replacement/flags` as in `sed` except that in `perl` we can also write it `s{pattern}{replacement}flags` which helps with nesting and with legibility</sup>

Comment: I guess I'm missing here where the delimiters are? Can you explain a little what's happening here? I'm not opposed to using perl, but not used to it. In your first example it looks like the `s` part would be the starting delimiter and `gr` would be the end? Or is this a substitution within a substitution?

Comment: @AramPapazian, sorry I had overlooked that the delimiters were `start[` and `]end`, not just `[` and `]`. See edit.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you =D So basically the `$&` is the text `.*?` in the first part of the substitution and you perform a secondary substitution on the string. Never seen this format, looks awesome =)

Comment: @AramPapazian, `$&` contains what was matched by the whole regexp (`start\[.*?\]end`). If it contained only what was matched by `.*?`, that would end up removing the `start[` and `end[`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed only:

```bash
sed -r ':1;s/(start\[.*[^\])(_.*\]end)/\1\\\2/;t1' file
```

If you need to make a replacement, the `-i` flag is set last `-ri`

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk command for this job.
It is convenient to temporarily replace square brackets by another character such as #

```
cat yourfile.txt| tr '[]' '#'
```

Now pipe the above result to this command:

```
awk -F# 'OFS=""; {for (i=1;i<=NF; i++)  if(i%2==0){ gsub("\\\\","",$i);gsub("_","\\_",$i);$i="["$i"]"} print $0}'
```

Comment: I think this misses two key parts of what I asked: 1. I don't want a "temporary replacement" as it might throw in extra problems in there. (For example, there might be a `#` in the string which now will cause problems when I unreplace). 2. It looks like this is substituting *all* instances whereas I need it *only* between certain delimiters. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: You can use any character, not just # (for example | is another option.). Also the code first removes all backslashes inside, and then puts a backslash ahead of all underlines. Just try it.

Comment: That wouldn't allow for `[`, `]`, or ```\``` in any other context in the input.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk -v RS=']end' '{ORS=RT} match($0,/(.*start\[)(.*)/,a) { gsub(/\\?_/,"\\_",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] } 1' file
Pretending_we have \_ some start[text that\_is really\_cool]end.
Then \_nothing_ would start[happen\_ to\_ that crew\_]end
```